# Giving color to text in php

Tags: html, css, text

I wanna give color to text in this string

I have tried this code but it's not working

```
<span style="color:red;"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></span>
```

This is my original code

```
<?php echo $category['name']; ?>
```

I have category names in the header menu and I wanna change their text color from the default color

Comment: Try giving `!important` property to css

Comment: `<span style="color:red !important;"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></span>`

Comment: FYI: I removed the PHP-tag (since that's not actually a part of your issue. It will simply echo a string, which seems to work). I also added the CSS and HTML-tags.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It might be some sort of PHP issue, if the var `$category['name']` has a value of `<span style="color: black !important">Sometext</span>` Or something of that sort

Comment: Your code is right but it's happened maybe CSS precedency or hierarchy

Comment: @yunzen - Since the OP haven't mentioned anything about the text not showing up, I would still call this a CSS-issue. Even if the category would contain HTML-code, it's not a "PHP-issue" since PHP still does exactly what it should, outputting the string.

Comment: Can you post the final generated code instead, there must be some history or edit on this question. It seems very strange people are suggesting to add important based on the current question

Comment: Recommending `!important` without knowing the cause of the issue is not good in my opinion. `!important` should be the last solution.